# set AutoLayout from Storyboard to uiview, Uibutton not spread equally in Uiview (constraints )

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uibutton, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xn9Gr.png)**I have set Constraints Of 
first Uiview (0,0,320,530)
second uiview(0,0,320,38)
in second view there are five UIbuttons with equal size (64,38)**

**problem is five Uibuttons not spread equally** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/di0q5.png)

I got message like

Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
2015-10-08 17:18:57.971 Profit Karma[5261:139743] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fc861543c20 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fc8614ac0e0(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fc86156eef0 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fc8614ac0e0.bottom == UIView:0x7fc861493c70.bottom>",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
2015-10-08 17:18:57.972 Profit Karma[5261:139743] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
2015-10-08 17:18:57.974 Profit Karma[5261:139743] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
2015-10-08 17:18:57.975 Profit Karma[5261:139743] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fc861543c20 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fc8614ac0e0(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fc86156eef0 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fc8614ac0e0.bottom == UIView:0x7fc861493c70.bottom>",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
2015-10-08 17:18:57.978 Profit Karma[5261:139743] navigationController : -47.000000 -64.000000 414.000000 44.000000
2015-10-08 17:18:57.982 Profit Karma[5261:139743] userDisplayTempScreen 1
2015-10-08 17:18:58.000 Profit Karma[5261:139743] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
2015-10-08 17:18:58.002 Profit Karma[5261:139743] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fc8614f0120 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fc8616009b0(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fc8614d5a30 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fc8616009b0.bottom == UIView:0x7fc8614fb550.bottom>",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
2015-10-08 17:18:58.004 Profit Karma[5261:139743] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
2015-10-08 17:18:58.006 Profit Karma[5261:139743] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fc8614f0120 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fc8616009b0(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fc8614d5a30 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fc8616009b0.bottom == UIView:0x7fc8614fb550.bottom>",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
2015-10-08 17:18:58.007 Profit Karma[5261:139743] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
2015-10-08 17:18:58.021 Profit Karma[5261:139743] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fc8614f0120 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fc8616009b0(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fc8614d5a30 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fc8616009b0.bottom == UIView:0x7fc8614fb550.bottom>",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
2015-10-08 17:18:58.111 Profit Karma[5261:139743] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
2015-10-08 17:18:58.112 Profit Karma[5261:139743] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
2015-10-08 17:18:58.114 Profit Karma[5261:139743] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
2015-10-08 17:18:58.117 Profit Karma[5261:139743] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fc8614f0120 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fc8616009b0(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fc8614d5a30 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fc8616009b0.bottom == UIView:0x7fc8614fb550.bottom>",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
2015-10-08 17:18:58.119 Profit Karma[5261:139743] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fc8614f0120 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fc8616009b0(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fc8614d5a30 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fc8616009b0.bottom == UIView:0x7fc8614fb550.bottom>",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.

Comment: i made constraints through pin from storyboard so please tell me how can i send constrains to you

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/di0q5.png

Comment: we need to know what constraints you have given to your view and to your buttons

Comment: I wonder, why there are'nt any constraint values in the error log you posted. Did you remove them ? or you get the same error log without the constraint values ? I am asking about this "", "", "", "",

Comment: Thanks Mr. T and El Captain for your response 

Pls click below link to get demo project
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5mabdphYDhzcVhrS2habXhmQ0U/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In demo project which are given by you, in that I just deleted all width and height constraints except bottomview height constraints....

Deleted height and width constraints of Buttons and give equal width constraints to all buttons....

And thats it...problem solved

Here is the working Project...

[Working Project link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=38554262293328999397)

So the final constraints are:---

- Pinned all edges of both UIViews
- Set height to Bottom view
- Pinned all edges of all buttons and give equal width

Comment: Thanks from bottom of my heart EI Captain "I salute Captain".
I can not give positive vote to your question because i do not have 15 points. 
when i have 15 points i will give positive vote toy you
can you please refer some documents so i can enhance my knowledge about pinned and NSConstraints

Comment: Accept my answer by select checkmark below voting counter...@AnkurPatel

Comment: @AnkurPatel check this...http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2